# Convergence of $L^p$ norms

Tags: inequality, convergence-divergence, asymptotics, normed-spaces

Given a measure space $X$ with its measure $\mu$, it can be shown (I'll provide a proof if asked for) that
$\displaystyle \forall f \in L^\infty(X,\mu),~\textrm{if } \exists p_0:\forall q \geq p_0, f\in L^q\cap L^\infty, \textrm{ then } \lim_{p \to \infty}\|f\|_p = \|f\|_\infty$ (whih by the way justify this notation)

This convergence implies the following:
$\forall f, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists q:= q(f,\epsilon),\textrm{ such that } \forall p\geq q, |\|f\|_p-\|f\|_\infty| < \epsilon$

This means that given an approximation error of the infinity norm bounded by $\epsilon$, I should be able to compute an (let's call it) index so that, I don't need to go any further, but I have *a priori* knowledge of the potential error.

The idea is, I am working on some pattern recognition problems and I am using the infinity norm somewhere there. However, as it is quite unreliable against outliers, using a p-norm approximation allows to "average out" the local outliers and get a more robust result. The higher the power the more importance the local outliers (or singularities) have, and the less I like it :)

If you have any idea on a proof or a results, it would be very helpful.

Comment: In general it sounds not too good to "average" outliers (since they are outliers and hence, distort the mean quite heavy). How about calculating the infinity norm, but leaving out a few of the largest contributions?

Comment: Well, even though some points can be considered as outliers, they may carry a bit of information anyway, or we cannot distinguish if they proper information carrier or information destroyer sometimes (see for instance the problems in OCT imaging). As a basic example, you can think of the Hausdorff distance in image alignment: http://www.vividsolutions.com/jcs/images/caseStudies/polygonMatching/Hausdorff%20Distance.png The two sets seem to be pretty well aligned, if we take out the peak, but taking this peak into consideration tells us also that the shapes are quite different.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242779/limit-of-lp-norm?noredirect=1&lq=1