# $\lim_{p\to \infty}\Vert f\Vert_{p}=\Vert f\Vert_{\infty}$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Limit of $L^p$ norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242779/limit-of-lp-norm)

On the $L_p$ spaces, when is $$\lim_{p\to \infty}\| f\|_{p}=\| f\|_{\infty}$$ true? Or what condition is necessary for this?

Comment: This is always true, however, if the space is not $\sigma$-finite you need a funky definition of $||\cdot ||_\infty$

Comment: @user45150: Why is that so? What is wrong in the non $\sigma$-finite case?

Answer (score 5):

It's a relatively easy proof that this holds in $L_p(X)$ for $f \in L^\infty(X)$ iff $\mu (X) < \infty$. The following was an exercise in Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*:

> Suppose $\mu$ is a positive measure on $X, \mu(X) < \infty, f \in L^\infty(\mu),||f||_\infty > 0, \text{and}$
>   $$a_n = \int_X|f|^n\,d\mu~~~~~(n=1,2,3,...).$$
>   prove that$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = ||f||_\infty$$

That you might want to try to develop a further understanding.

Comment: I can see how $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \leq ||f||_\infty$$, but how do you show the other direction?

Comment: I could not see it, how this limit is equal to $\Vert f \Vert_\infty$, thanks

Comment: I have no idea where is the part $\mu(X)<\infty$ from.

Answer (score 4):

If $\|f\|_\infty<\infty$, then for the property to hold it is necessary and sufficient that there exists $p<\infty$ such that $\|f\|_p<\infty$.  The only way for this to always hold is for the measure space to have finite total measure.

If $\|f\|_\infty=\infty$, then it holds regardless.