# $L^\infty$ norm as limit of $L^p$-norm

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Assume $X$ a measurable space, with $\mu(X) = +\infty$. I want to proof that if $|f|_p \le c$ for every $p$ then $f$ belongs to $L^{\infty}$ and $|f|_{\infty} \le c$.
[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2353709/f-p-to-f-infty-under-general-assumptions/3746338#3746338) it's already been asked a similar question, but I'm little bit confused if the answer marked as "right answer" really worked with a general measurable set, without assumption of finite measure.

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: The answer in that link does work. You only need $\|f\|_p<\infty$ for some $p$ for that proof to work.

Comment: @geetha290krm so, the result still holds even if $\mu(X) = +\infty$? Did you have any reference?

Comment: The accepted answer in your link does not assume that $\mu (X) <\infty$. Why do you need another reference?

Comment: Yes, but I need use this result in my thesis, but my advisor don't seems believe in the result. i think that if i shown it in a book... sorry @geetha290krm

Comment: So, I show for him this proof and he said that it isn't good. For this, I want to find this result in some book, paper, something like that

Comment: What they proved in that accepted answer is an exercise in Rudin's RCA. (The 4th question in the chapter on $L^{p}$ spaces in the old edition that I have).

Comment: Than you so much. Sorry me again!

Comment: @RodolfoFerreiradeOliveira: The answer I posted in the link you are referring to works whether $\mu$ is a finite measure or not.