# $\lim_{p \to \infty} \bigg ( \sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i |x_i|^p \bigg )^{1/p} = \max _{1 \leq i\leq m} |x_{i}|$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification, lp-spaces

Let $\mathbb K$ denote $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$. I'm trying to prove the discrete version of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/640489/convergence-from-lp-to-l-infty) result, i.e.,

> Let $x= (x_1, \ldots, x_m) \in \mathbb K^m$ and $\lambda=(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_m) \in \mathbb R_{\ge 0}^m$. Then
> $$
> \lim_{p \to \infty} \bigg ( \sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i |x_i|^p \bigg )^{1/p} = \max _{1 \leq i\leq m} |x_{i}|.
> $$

Could you confirm if my below attempt is correct?

---

**Proof** WLOG, we assume $x_1 = \max _{1 \leq i\leq m} |x_{i}|$. Then
$$
 (\lambda_1 |x_1|^p)^{1/p} \le  \bigg ( \sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i |x_i|^p \bigg )^{1/p} \le  \bigg ( |x_1|^p \sum_{i=1}^m  \lambda_i  \bigg )^{1/p}.
$$

We take the limit $p \to \infty$ and get
$$
\begin{align}
\liminf_{p\to\infty} (\lambda_1 |x_1|^p)^{1/p} &\le  \liminf_{p\to\infty} \bigg ( \sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i |x_i|^p \bigg )^{1/p} \le  \liminf_{p\to\infty} \bigg ( |x_1|^p \sum_{i=1}^m  \lambda_i  \bigg )^{1/p} \\
\limsup_{p\to\infty} (\lambda_1 |x_1|^p)^{1/p} &\le  \limsup_{p\to\infty} \bigg ( \sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i |x_i|^p \bigg )^{1/p} \le  \limsup_{p\to\infty} \bigg ( |x_1|^p \sum_{i=1}^m  \lambda_i  \bigg )^{1/p}.
\end{align}
$$

The claim then follows by noticing that

$$
\lim_{p\to \infty} (\lambda_1)^{1/p} =\lim_{p \to \infty}\bigg (\sum_{i=1}^m  \lambda_i  \bigg )^{1/p}=0.
$$

This completes the proof.

Comment: Your last line should read “$=1$” but looks ok other than that

Comment: Since it seems there is really not much to say about your proof, I voted to close (and the answer there are somewhat similar to what you did here)

Comment: @Masacroso $(\lambda_1 |x_1|^p)^{1/p} = (\lambda_1)^{1/p} |x_1|$...

Comment: **Big error.**  You said $\lambda=(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_m) \in \mathbb R_{\ge 0}^m$.  But if the maximum of $|x_i|$ occurs where $\lambda_i=0$, this result fails.

Comment: @Akira, alright, I didn't paid enough attention that $\lambda _1|x_1|^p\leqslant \lambda _1|x_1|^p+\ldots +\lambda _n|x_n|^p$, yes, your first equality is right, sorry. However you last two equalities are wrong in general, because if $\lambda _1=0$ and $\lambda _2=1$...

Comment: It's a typo. I forgot to assume $\lambda_i \neq0$ for all $i$.

Comment: Any reason for a downvote...?