# If $f \in L^{\infty}$ and $\exists r < \infty$ so that $\|f\|_r < \infty$, show $\lim_{p \rightarrow \infty} \|f\|_p = \|f\|_{\infty}$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

**Question:**
This is the last part of a 5 part question I am working on.
Let $(X,\mu)$ be a possibly infinite measure space. Assume $\exists r < \infty$ with $\|f\|_r < \infty$ and that $\|f \|_{\infty} < \infty$. Show that $\lim_{p \rightarrow \infty} \|f_p\| = \|f\|_{\infty}$.

This is from Real and Complex by Rudin, chapter 3 exercise 14.

**Progress:**
I have shown that $\|f\|_{\infty} \le \lim_{p \rightarrow \infty} \|f\|_p$ as follows,

Fix $\epsilon > 0$. Let $E = \{x : |f(x)| > \|f\|_{\infty} - \epsilon \}$. Then observe
$$ \|f\|_p \ge \left( \int_{E} |f|^p d\mu \right)^{1/p} > \left( \int_{E}(\| f \|_{\infty} - \epsilon)^{p} d\mu \right)^{1/p} = \left( \|f\|_{\infty} - \epsilon \right) \mu(E)^{1/p}, $$
thus, $\lim_{p \rightarrow \infty} \|f\|_p \ge \|f\|_{\infty} - \epsilon$ since $\mu(E) < \infty$.

I attempted something similar for the other direction, but could not say the measure of a set was finite like (I think) I need for this argument to work. Here is what I tried:

Since $\|f\|_r < \infty, \exists R$ so that $|x| > R \implies f(x) < \frac{1}{2}$. Let $A = \{ x : |x| \le R \}$ and $B = \{x : |x| > R \}$. Then,
$$\|f\|_{p} \le \left( \int_{A} |f|^p d \mu + \int_{B} \frac{1}{2^p} d\mu\right)^{1/p} = \left( \int_{A} |f|^p d\mu + \frac{1}{2^p} \mu( B ) \right)^{1/p}.$$

If $\mu(B) < \infty$ this can easily show the desired result. Moreover, if I could show that there is a family of sets $\{B_p\}$ that act similarly so that $\mu(B_p)$ grows slower than $e^p$, then I can also complete the proof.

Thoughts?

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242779/limit-of-lp-norm).

Comment: I was trying to find somewhere on the site where this was already asked, and could not find it. However, now that you found it for me, I don't see how they showed this direction. It reads,

$$\|f\|_p \le \left( \int_{X} |f(x)|^{p-q} |f(x)|^{q} d\mu \right)^{1/p} \le \|f\|_{\infty}^{\frac{p-q}{p}}\|f\|_{q}^{q/p}.$$

I think the first inequality should just be an equality OR they intended $|f(x)|^{p-q}$ to be $\|f\|_{\infty}^{p-q}$. Even in this latter case, I do not see how the 2nd inequality follows.

Comment: The second inequality is straightforward: all that is happening is that the first $|f(x)|$ is bounded by $\|f\|_\infty$.

Comment: Wow. Of course. Thank you. I had convinced myself it should be via Holder. (As did the answer below... because as I now see it's a very simple case of Holder's.)

Comment: But it is Hölder. I answered on the comment to my answer.

Comment: This is part e) (5) of Question 4 from Chapter 3 Exercises of Rudin Real and Complex Analysis (RCA Exercise 3.4.e). Adding this comment so it can be easier to find this question while searching via search engines. It took me some time to find this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the first part you have to use $\liminf$, as you don't still know that the limit exists.

For the second part, you are thinking as if $X$ was $\mathbb R^n$, which it might not be. One way of attacking the problem along your line of thought  would be to assume $\|f\|_\infty=1$ (i.e., work with $f/\|f\|_\infty$). Then, for $p>r$,
$$
\left(\int_X|f|^pd\mu\right)^{1/p}\leq\left(\int_X|f|^rd\mu\right)^{1/p}=\|f\|_r^{r/p}
$$
Then 
$$
\limsup_{p\to\infty}\|f\|_p\leq1.
$$
Now you can scale back with $\|f\|_\infty$ to get 
$$
\limsup_{p\to\infty}\|f\|_p\leq\|f\|_\infty.
$$

Another way of doing this second part is to use Hölder's inequality:
$$
\|f\|_p^p=\int_X|f|^pd\mu=\int_X|f|^r|f|^{p-r}d\mu\leq \|f\|_\infty^{p-r}\,\|f\|_r^r.
$$
So
$$
\limsup_{p\to\infty}\|f\|_p\leq\limsup_{p\to\infty}\|f\|_\infty^{(p-r)/p}\,\|f\|_r^{r/p}=\|f\|_\infty.
$$

Comment: I like your first way. I feel silly for not thinking of passing to $r$ with how much time I spent on this. Also, for the latter, does Holder's inequality hold for $1 \le p \le \infty?$ I've only seen it for $1 < p < \infty$.

Comment: Yes, Hölder holds for $1,\infty$ too. The proof is straightforward: $$ \int |f|\,|g|\leq\int \|f\|_\infty\,|g|=\|f\|_\infty\,\int|g|=\|f\|_\infty\,\|g\|_1.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer(s) and clarifications. Helps a lot!

Comment: You are very welcome. Most of us love users who post thoughtful questions.