# Showing that $\|f\|_p\to\|f\|_{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I know this question has been asked a lot in this site, I've been checking those questions myself, however according to the theory we use in class there are things that I can't use and/or I don't know how to use (for example, we don't work with probability spaces, and other things that are *very* measure theory). So this is another version of this same old problem.

> If $|\Omega|<\infty$, $f\in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$, then $$\|f\|_{\infty}=\lim_{p\to{\infty}}|\Omega|^{-1/p}\|f\|_p$$

I see, that this problem really is like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242779/limit-of-lp-norm) one, since is easy to see that $\lim_{p\to\infty}|\Omega|^{-1/p}=1$.

Now, we are given two hints:

> Prove that: **(a)** $|\Omega|^{-1/p}\|f\|_p\le\|f\|_{\infty},\forall p$. 
>   
> **(b)** If $\varepsilon>0$ then $|\Omega|^{-1/p}\|f\|_p\ge\|f\|_{\infty}-\varepsilon$ for $p$ sufficiently big.

For the first one, it comes easily from a proposition that says, if $|\Omega|<\infty$ and $p<\infty$ then $\|f\|_p\le|\Omega|^{1/p}\|f\|_{\infty}$, if $|\Omega|\not=0$ then we have that $|\Omega|^{-1/p}\|f\|_p\le\|f\|_{\infty}$.

Now onto proving the second one. I'm having a lot of trouble, I used an idea from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/242792/80965), but instead of getting the measure of $\Omega$, I get the measure of a subset, and I'm not using that $p$ has to be big or not, that part of the hint confuses me really, I can't see how do you use it for the problem.

Comment: Many times indeed. Click in [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/242779/8271) and then look at the Linked column

Comment: Hi For Ana Galois' answer, there is one point that I don't understand. You say the measure of set A is positive and this is from the definition of sup norm, however I think by definition, for each \epsilon, there exists x such that the inequality is true. My confusion is whether there are many x in A such that the measure of A is positive. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The adjoint teacher solved the problem, I'm writting down just in case somebody got stuck like myself even though the solution is pretty simple (I know that now). I hope I don't mess it up.

Let's prove the hints:

**(a)** Is already solved in the question by that proposition.

**(b)** Let $\varepsilon>0$. Let's take the following set: $A=\{x\in\Omega: |f(x)|\ge\|f\|_\infty -\varepsilon\}$, wich satisfies $|A|>0$ because of the definition of $\|\cdot\|_\infty$, then it follows that: 
$$|\Omega|^{-1/p}\|f\|_p=\left(\frac{1}{|\Omega|}\|f\|_p\right)^{-1/p}\le\left(\frac{(\|f\|_\infty-\varepsilon)^p}{|\Omega|}\int_A 1_\Omega\right)^{1/p}=(\|f\|_\infty-\varepsilon)\left(\frac{|A|}{|\Omega|}\right)^{1/p}:=(\star)$$

but since $\left(\frac{|A|}{|\Omega|}\right)^{1/p}\to 1$ when $p\to\infty$, then $(\star)\to(\|f\|_\infty-\varepsilon)$.

From here the rest is history, and is pretty easy to finish.

Now we have another way to see $$\lim_{p\to\infty}\|f\|_p=\|f\|_\infty$$
with relation to the measure of the set $$\lim_{p\to\infty}|\Omega|^{-1/p}\|f\|_p=\|f\|_\infty$$ (well, maybe is not that impressive, but it's another way to see it).