# Using concavity of log to prove $L^p$ norm is increasing in $p$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, logarithms, convex-analysis, lp-spaces

In [this](http://www.personal.psu.edu/axk29/502/norminequality.pdf) proof that $p \mapsto \|f\|_p$ is an increasing function of $p > 0$ (for fixed $f \in L^p$ on a finite measure space) the approach is to show that $\frac{d}{dp} \|f\|_p \geq 0$, which ends up being equivalent to
$$
\int |f|^p \ln|f|^p \geq \ln \int |f|^p.
$$
It's stated in the final paragraph that one can approximate the integrals by finite sums and use the concavity of $\ln$ to prove that inequality. I'm having trouble with this though. Can someone sketch this out in more detail to help me understand?

Comment: This is not true in general https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1397097/how-to-show-that-lp-norm-is-monotone-increasing?rq=1

Comment: True; let's assume we're working with the Lebesgue measure on a compact interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, lets assume that we have a finite measure space with measure $\mu(\Omega)=1$.
Because if $\mu(\Omega)>1$ then the claim is wrong, using $f=1$ as a counterexample.

Then the last equation from the linked pdf
$$
\int |f|^p \ln |f|^p \geq
\int |f|^p \ln \int |f|^p
$$
is true because the function $g(x)= x \ln(x)$ is convex and then we can directly apply [Jensen's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Measure-theoretic_and_probabilistic_form).