# If all $L^p$ norms are bounded then the $L^\infty$ is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Suppose that $||f||_p \le K$ for all $1 \le p <\infty$ for some $K>0$.
How to show that the essential supremum exists and bounded by $K$ that i s$||f||_\infty \le K$?

I know how to prove that if $f \in L^\infty$ then 
\begin{align}
lim_{p \to \infty} ||f||_p=||f||_\infty
\end{align}
but this already assume that $f \in L^\infty$ in this question we have to show that $f$ has an essential supremum. To be more precise I don't think I can use a technique when I define
\begin{align}
A_\epsilon =\{ x | \ |f(x)|>||f||_{\infty}-\epsilon \}
\end{align}

I feel like here we have to use some converges theorem.
Thanks for any help

Comment: Any condition on the measure space?

Comment: Assume it's finite

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limit of $L^p$ norm](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242779/limit-of-lp-norm)

Comment: Thanks. But I am asking something different. I am not assuming that $f$ has an essential supremum before hand we have to show it.

Comment: If $\|f\|_\infty =\infty$, then for all $n$ there is $A_n$ with $\mu(A_n)>0$  so that $|f|\ge n$ on $A_n$. Then $\|f\|_n \ge (\mu(A_n) n^n)^\frac{1}{n} \to \infty$. Thus that contradicts your assumption (But I do agree that this question is not a direct duplicate, but your problem can be solved using that anyway).

Comment: @JohnMa What if $\mu(A_n)$ goes to zero faster than $n^{-n}$?

Comment: Um.... Good point @Ian

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assume $\| f \|_\infty=\infty$. Let $M>0$. Define $A_M=\{ |f| \geq M \}$. Then $\mu(A_M)>0$. Take $p$ so large that $\mu(A_M)^{1/p} \geq 1/2$, then $\| f \|_p \geq (\mu(A_M) M^p)^{1/p} \geq M/2$. Since $M$ was arbitrary, $f$ is not uniformly bounded in $L^p$, and your result follows by contraposition.

This is essentially the argument suggested by John Ma in the comments, but decoupling $M$ and $p$.

Comment: Ok. I get it thank you.

Comment: The result still it holds if $K=K(p)$ and $K(p) \to C$ as $p\to +infty$? In $\mathbb{R}^n$ it holds as well?

Comment: @RodolfoFerreiradeOliveira If $K \to C$ as $p \to \infty$ then $K$ is uniformly bounded anyway. The only way that would fail would be if $K$ were sometimes infinite, but now you just restrict attention to $p$'s larger than all those where $K$ is infinite. And yes, this holds in whatever measure space. It also holds in the sense of the $p$ norms in $\mathbb{R}^n$ since these can be viewed as $L^p$ norms under the counting measure in a finite set.

Answer (score 5):

I am going to assume that $f\geq 0$ (otherwise replace $f$ with $|f|$).
Consider 
$$g = \min(f,K + 1)\in L^{\infty}.$$
Then $\|g\|_p\leq \|f\|_p\leq K$ hence
$$\|g\|_\infty = \lim_{p \rightarrow \infty} \|g\|_p \leq K$$
so
$$ \min(f,K + 1) \leq K \ \ \ a.e. \implies f\leq K a.e.$$

Comment: Very nice argument!