# $L^p$ norm converges to $L^\infty$ norm

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

The question is: Let $ (X,\mathcal M,\mu) $ be an arbitrary measure space. Let $f$ be a function in $L^r$ for some $0<r<\infty$. Show that $||f||_p$ converges to $||f||_\infty$ as $p\to \infty$.

> Now I have shown that this is true under the additional assumptions that $||f||_\infty<\infty$, and that $f$ is a simple function. Now let $f$ be nonnegative and let $s_n$ be increasing to $f$ where $s_n$'s are simple functions with finite measure support. But how could I pass to limits? What I am arguing is:
>   \begin{align}
> \lim_{p\to\infty}||f||_p&=\lim_{p\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}||s_n||_p, \text{ (Monotone Convergence Theorem)}\\
> &=\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{p\to\infty}||s_n||_p\\
> &=\lim_{n\to\infty}||s_n||_\infty=||f||_\infty
> \end{align}
>   But I cannot justify switching limits in the second line. How could I do this? Or alternatively, is there another proof that avoids the progressive argument?

Comment: It is an arbitrary measure space.

Comment: The [answer by Davide Giraudo](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/242792) is for an arbitrary measure space, and is the simplest way to handle this problem.