# Calculation of a limit including intervals

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

The question statement is as follows: Consider a continuous function $f : [a,b] \to \Re^+$ and $M_p = (\int_a^b (f(x))^p dx )^\frac{1}{p}$, prove that $\lim_{p \to +\infty} M_p = \max_{x\in[a,b]} f(x)$

After some thinking I've gotten to the result that $\lim_{p \to +\infty} log(M_p) = \lim_{p \to +\infty} \frac{\int_a^b log(f(x))(f(x))^p dx}{\int_a^b (f(x))^p dx }$ but I don't know how to move forward from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is already on the site : are you fine with getting a complete answer?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon yeah, that would be alright!

Comment: Thanks, let me be of service. The point is that the question you have is actually phrased in a more general setting , a bit like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242779/limit-of-lp-norm). I will have to search for one that is more basic in nature.

Comment: Yes, @CataSequence I think you should take a look at the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1662555/limit-of-lp-norms-for-continuous-functions), which contains an attempted proof that I know is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much @TeresaLisbon. I think that settles it.

Comment: Welcome! I will close the question as a duplicate, since you already have the answer.