# Prove $\lim \|f\|_p=\|f\|_\infty$ for Borel measure (Domain has infinite measure)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ denote a Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Assume that $f\in L^1_\mu(\mathbb{R}^n)\cap L_\mu^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Prove that
$$\large\lim_{p\to\infty}\|f\|_{L_\mu^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}=\|f\|_{L_\mu^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)}$$

---

My attempt: I know how to prove it for the case of Lebesgue measure, provided the critical assumption that **the space $E$ has finite measure**. Here, the method doesn't seem to work since $\mathbb{R}^n$ has infinite measure. Perhaps use the fact that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is sigma-finite? I am unsure of the details though.

We can note that $f\in L_\mu^P(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for any $1\leq p\leq\infty$ since $\int|f|^p\,d\mu=\int|f||f|^{p-1}\,d\mu\leq\|f\|_{L_\mu^\infty}^{p-1}\int|f|\,d\mu<\infty$.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note

$$\begin{split} 
\|f\|_{L^{p+1}\ \ (\mu)} &= \left(\int_{\mathbb R^n} |f|^{p+1}d\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{p+1}} \\
&= \left(\int_{\mathbb R^n} |f|^p |f|d\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{p} \frac{p}{p+1}} \\
&=\big( \|f \| _{L^p(\nu)}\big)^{\frac{p}{p+1}},
\end{split}$$

where $d\nu = |f| d\mu$. Since $f\in L^1(\mu)$, $\nu(\mathbb R^n)<\infty$ and so using the finite case ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242779/limit-of-lp-norm)) we have

$$ \lim_{p\to \infty} \|f\|_{L^p(\mu)} = \|f\|_{L^\infty(\nu)}.$$

and it is easy to show $ \|f\|_{L^\infty(\nu)} =  \|f\|_{L^\infty(\mu)}$: Pick $c > \| f\|_{L^\infty(\nu)}$ and $c> 0$. Then by definition,

$$ 0=  \nu (|f|\ge c) = \int_{|f|\ge c} |f| d\mu \ge c\mu(|f|\ge c).$$

Thus $\mu(|f|\ge c) = 0$ and $c \ge\|f\|_{L^\infty(\mu)}$. Since $c$ is arbitrary we have

$$ \|f\|_{L^\infty(\nu)}\ge \|f\|_{L^\infty(\mu)}.$$

(Note that $\|f\|_{L^\infty(\mu) }= \inf\{ c>0: \mu(|f|\ge c) = 0\}$).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you explain how to conclude $\nu(\mathbb{R^n})<\infty$? I am not very familiar with this "changing of measure".

Comment: $\nu(\mathbb R^n) = \int_{\mathbb R^n} 1 d\nu = \int_{\mathbb R^n} |f|d\mu$. @yoyostein

Comment: Excellent. Got it.

Comment: One last question, how do we show $\|f\|_{L^\infty(\nu)}=\|f\|_{L^\infty(\mu)}$? I can show $\|f\|_{L^\infty(\nu)}\leq\|f\|_{L^\infty(\mu)}$ since if $\mu(A)=0$ implies $\nu(A)=0$. However the other inequality ($\nu(A)=0$ implies $\mu(A)=0$) seems not so obvious? Thanks.

Comment: @yoyostein please see the edit.