# Needs clarification in a proof--

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

I 'm not getting the solution by **David Giraudo** for [Limit of $L^p$ norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242779/limit-of-lp-norm) completely.
The step in which i'm having problem is

> As $|f(x)|\leqslant\lVert f\rVert_\infty$ for almost every $x$, we
>    have for $p>q$, $$ \lVert
>  f\rVert_p\leqslant\left(\int_X|f(x)|^{p-q}|f(x)|^qd\mu\right)^{1/p}\leqslant
>  \lVert f\rVert_\infty^{\frac{p-q}p}\lVert f\rVert_q^{q/p},$$

Please give the detailed explanation for this completely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first inequality is actually an equality since $|f(x)|^p=|f(x)|^{p-q}|f(x)|^q$.

To get to the second step, replace $|f(x)|^{p-q}$ by $\|f\|_{\infty}^{p-q}$, which you can do since $|f(x)| \leq \|f\|_{\infty}$, and factor it out of the integral. Also note that $\left(\int_X |f(x)|^q \ d\mu\right)^{1/p} =\left( \left(\int_X |f(x)|^q \ d\mu \right)^{1/q} \right)^{q/p} = \|f\|_q^{q/p}$.

Comment: :Thank you very much!! :-))