# Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\int ^b_af(x)^n dx)^\frac{1}{n}=\sup _{x \in [a,b]} f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f\in C[a,b]$. prove that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\int ^b_af(x)^n dx\right)^\frac{1}{n}=\sup _{x \in [a,b]} |f(x)|$$

i really have no idea where to start

Comment: Wouldn't you have to write there some absolute value(s)?

Comment: @DonAntonio..I did't get your point sir

Comment: There is a result that looks similiar and is about $L^p$-norms. But I think your equality might hold as well.

Comment: Suresh: if for example $\;f(x)\;$ is negative ,that integral is going to get infinitely many times a negative value...and the same is true for positive values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit of $L^p$ norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242779/limit-of-lp-norm)

Comment: @ArnaudMortier This question is much more elementary than the one you link to, which belongs more to advanced calculus or functional analysis, and it would probably confuse the OP. This question can be given in a first undergraduate year course, the other one belongs more towards the end of undergraduate studies.

Comment: @DonAntonio it is not necessary to understand the terms of this other question to understand the given answer and see that it answers exactly what the OP asks here.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I don't agree with you at all: there are terms that for a first yearer could be like chinese and even in the case the OP was curious enough to read about them, that'd take him way too astray from a basic solution as the one given in the answer below, say.

Answer (score 2):

I assume $f$ is positive (as stated there is a problem with the left term).

Let $C := \sup_{[a,b]} f(x)$

$\left(\int ^b_af(x)^n dx\right)^\frac{1}{n} ≤ \left(\int ^b_aC^n dx\right)^\frac{1}{n} = C(b-a)^{1/n}$

Now, fix $\epsilon$ and consider $[c,d], d >c$ on which $f(x) > C - \epsilon$

$\left(\int ^b_af(x)^n dx\right)^\frac{1}{n} ≥ \left(\int ^d_cf(x)^n dx\right)^\frac{1}{n} ≥ (C- \epsilon)(d-c)^{1/n}$

To conclude, use $y^{1/n} \to 1$, for all $y > 0$.