# $\lim_{n\to \infty}(\int_0^1 f(x)^{2n}g(x)^n h(x)~dx)^{1/n}$ where $f,g,h$ are positive continuous functions on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

I want to find $\lim_{n\to \infty}(\int_0^1 f(x)^{2n}g(x)^n h(x)~dx)^{1/n}$ where $f,g,h$ are positive continuous functions on $[0,1]$. By Holder's inequality, this limit is greater than  or equal to $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^1 f(x)^2g(x)h(x)^{1/n}~dx$ which is equal to $\int_0^1 f(x)^2g(x)~dx$ by the DCT. But I can't find an upper bound. I tried Jensen's inequality, but it does not seems to work I think because $x\mapsto x^{1/n}$ is not convex. Can I get a hint?

Comment: Maybe you can use the min and max of $h$. The you get bounds for the $L_n$ norm of $f^2g$. The $\|;\|_n|$ as n tents to infinity may be then what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $k=f^{2}g$, $M_{k}=\max_{x\in[0,1]}k(x)$, and $M_{h}=\max_{x\in[0,1]}h(x)$.
Firstly, observe that
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \left\{ \int_{0}^{1}k^{n}(x)h(x)dx\right\} ^{\frac{1}{n}}\\
 & \leq & M_{k}M_{h}^{\frac{1}{n}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore $\limsup_{n}\left\{ \int_{0}^{1}k^{n}(x)h(x)dx\right\} ^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq M_{k}$.

Choose $x_{0}\in[0,1]$ such that $k(x_{0})=M_{k}$. Let $\alpha\in(0,1)$
be arbitrary. Since $k(x_{0})>\alpha M_{k}$, by continuity of $k$
at $x_{0}$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $k(x)>\alpha M_{k}$
whenever $x\in[x_{0}-\delta,x_{0}+\delta]$ (if $x_{0}=0$ or $x_{0}=1$,
adjust the interval accordingly). Let $b=\min_{x\in[0,1]}h(x)>0$.
We have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \left\{ \int_{0}^{1}k^{n}(x)h(x)dx\right\} ^{\frac{1}{n}}\\
 & \geq & \left\{ \int_{x_{0}-\delta}^{x_{0}+\delta}k^{n}(x)h(x)dx\right\} ^{\frac{1}{n}}\\
 & \geq & \alpha M_{k}b^{\frac{1}{n}}(2\delta)^{\frac{1}{n}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore, $\liminf_{n}\left\{ \int_{0}^{1}k^{n}(x)h(x)dx\right\} ^{\frac{1}{n}}\geq\alpha M_{k}$.
Further letting $\alpha\rightarrow1$, we have $\liminf_{n}\left\{ \int_{0}^{1}k^{n}(x)h(x)dx\right\} ^{\frac{1}{n}}\geq M_{k}$.
Hence, $\lim_{n}\left\{ \int_{0}^{1}k^{n}(x)h(x)dx\right\} ^{\frac{1}{n}}$
exists and equals to $M_{k}=\max_{x\in[0,1]}f^{2}(x)g(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Like I said in my comment to your question. Let $m_h=\min h$ and $M_h=\max h$ ($\min$ and $\max$ over the unit interval). These are finite and positive by your hypothesis. THen

$$m^{1/n}_h\|f^2g\|_n\leq \|f^2gh^{1/n}\|_n\leq \|f^2g\|_nM^{1/n}_h$$

Since $\|f^2g\|_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\|f^2g\|_\infty$, passing to the limit you obtain

$$\|f^2gh^{1/n}\|_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\|f^2g\|_\infty$$.

Here we have used a well known [result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242779/limit-of-lp-norm): if $f$ is integrable with respect a finite measure, then $\|f\|_p$ converges to $\|f\|_\infty$ as $p\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Continuity of $L^p$ norm, i.e., the continuity of the map $p\mapsto ||f||_p$, needs a proof.

Comment: Nice proof. Thanks