# unit norm function

Tags: functional-analysis

I want to show that for a unit norm weight $h > 0$ in $L^1$ with $\lVert h \rVert_1 = 1$ and a function $f \in L^{\infty}$ both defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$ that:

$$\Bigl(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f|^p h\Bigl)^{1/p} \to \lVert f \rVert_{\infty} \ \text{as  } p \to \infty$$

I thought of using Hölder's inequality with $q=1$ and $p=\infty$, but I have never done so with a weighted-norm.

Comment: This holds for all finite measure spaces, your case is the measure having $h$ as a density w.r.t. Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @Jochen. That is true? How can I work it out?

Comment: Kenny Wong gives the details in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Jochen's comment, the key insight is that if $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure and $h > 0$ is in $L^1(\lambda)$, then the measure $\nu$, defined by
$$ \nu(E) := \int_E h \ d\lambda$$
satisfies the following the properties:

- $\nu$ is a finite measure, i.e. $\nu(\mathbb R) < \infty$.
- $\lambda(E) = 0 \iff \nu(E) = 0$ for all measurable $E$.

Since $\lambda$ and $\nu$ have the same null sets, we have
$$\|f \|_{L^\infty(\lambda)} = \| f \|_{L^\infty(\nu)}.$$
In particular, $f \in L^{\infty}(\lambda) \iff f \in L^{\infty}(\nu)$.

Since $\nu$ is a finite measure, you can use [this argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242779/limit-of-lp-norm) to show that
$$ \lim_{p \to \infty} \| f \|_{L^p(\nu)} = \| f \|_{L^\infty(\nu)}.$$
for all $f \in L^{\infty}(\nu)$.

Now, $$\|f \|_{L^p(\nu)} = \left(\int_{\mathbb R} |f|^p h \ d\lambda\right)^{\frac 1 p},$$
by the definition of $\nu$.

Furthermore, we've already explained that any $f $ in $L^{\infty}(\lambda)$ is also in $L^{\infty}(\nu)$, and $\|f \|_{L^\infty(\nu)} = \| f \|_{L^\infty(\lambda)}$.

Thus
$$ \lim_{p \to \infty} \left(\int_{\mathbb R} |f|^p h \ d\lambda\right)^{\frac 1 p} = \| f \|_{L^\infty(\lambda)}$$
for all $f \in L^\infty(\lambda)$.