# Limit of $L^p$ norm of a function depending on $p$

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, analysis, measure-theory

### Background

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space (or a finite measure space).
Then, it is well-known that, for a fixed function $f$ with $\lVert f \rVert_\infty := \mathrm{ess.sup}_{x} \lvert f(x) \rvert < \infty$, we have
$$
\lVert f \rVert_p := \left( \int |f|^p \, dP \right)^{1/p}
\ 
\overset{p \to \infty}{\rightarrow}
\ 
\lVert f \rVert_\infty
\text{.}
$$
(See, e.g., [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/242779/1078103).)

I'm curious what happens if $f$ depends on $p$.
More precisely, suppose we have a sequence of functions $\{f_p\}_{p=1}^\infty \subset L^\infty$ that converges to $f \in L^\infty$ a.s.
Do we always have
$
\lim_{p \to \infty} \lVert f_p \rVert_p
=
\lVert f \rVert_\infty
$?
If not always, under what conditions?

### What I've tried so far

Maybe one of the possible sufficient conditions is that $|f_p| \nearrow |f|$ almost surely.
Under this condition, we can prove $\lim_{p \to \infty} \lVert f_p \rVert_p
= \lVert f \rVert_\infty$ as follows.

By the assumption, for any $p = 1, 2, \ldots$, we have $|f_p| \leq |f| \leq \lVert f \rVert_\infty$ a.s.
So the monotonicity of integral implies $\int |f_p|^p \, dP \leq \lVert f \rVert_\infty^p$, which proves $\limsup_{p \to \infty} \lVert f_p \rVert_p \leq \lVert f \rVert_\infty$.

Now we are going to prove $\liminf_{p \to \infty} \lVert f_p \rVert_p \geq \lVert f \rVert_\infty$.
To this end, fix any $\epsilon > 0$ and define the events
$A_p(\epsilon) := \{|f_p| > \lVert f \rVert_\infty - \epsilon\}$ for $p = 1, 2, \ldots$.
Then, we have
\begin{align}
\int_\Omega |f_p|^p \, dP
\geq 
\int_{A_p(\epsilon)} |f_p|^p \, dP
\geq 
\int_{A_p(\epsilon)} (\lVert f \rVert_\infty - \epsilon)^p \, dP
=
P(A_p(\epsilon)) (\lVert f \rVert_\infty - \epsilon)^p
\end{align}
and therefore
$$
\lVert f_p \rVert_p
\geq 
P(A_p(\epsilon))^{1/p} (\lVert f \rVert_\infty - \epsilon)
\text{.}
$$
Now, $|f_p| \nearrow |f|$ implies $A_p(\epsilon) \nearrow A(\epsilon) := \{|f| > \lVert f \rVert_\infty - \epsilon\}$.
Noting that $A(\epsilon)$ is a positive constant (by the definition of $\lVert f \rVert_\infty$), by the continuity of measure, we have
$$
\lim_{p \to \infty} P(A_p(\epsilon))^{1/p}
= 
P(A(\epsilon))^{0}
= 1
\text{.}
$$
Therefore, we have proven that
$\liminf_{p \to \infty} \lVert f_p \rVert_p \geq \lVert f \rVert_\infty - \epsilon$.
Since $\epsilon > 0$ can be taken arbitrarily small, we obtain
$\liminf_{p \to \infty} \lVert f_p \rVert_p \geq \lVert f \rVert_\infty$ as desired.

### Questions

So my questions are:

1. Is the proof that I wrote above correct?
2. Are there any other conditions under which we have $
   \lim_{p \to \infty} \lVert f_p \rVert_p
   =
   \lVert f \rVert_\infty
   $?
3. Are there any counterexamples?

Comment: First, I think your proof is correct.  Secondly, I think it is true without extra hypotheses - look up Egorov's Theorem.