# Counterexample of limiting of $\|f\|_p$

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Following this question: [Limit of $L^p$ norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242779/limit-of-lp-norm?noredirect=1&lq=1)

> Given a finite measure space $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ and a measurable function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ in $L^\infty$, $\displaystyle\lim_{p\to\infty}\|f\|_p=\|f\|_\infty$

Can we find a counterexample when $\mu$ is not a finite sigma measure?

Comment: This statement is true in general. You can patch the proof together from the answers to the exact question that you linked.

Comment: See if this works: as is pointed out in Davide's comment, the statement is true for $\sigma-$finite measure space, by using Levi's theorem. On the other hand, if $p\ge 1$ and $f\in L^p$, then $\{x: f(x)\ne 0\}$ is $\sigma-$finite, since $\{x: f(x)\ne 0\}=\{x:|f(x)|^p\ne 0\}=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_+}\{|f(x)|^p>\frac{1}{n}\}$.

Comment: Well, to be honest, Davide said it is true for $\sigma-$finite space, but I has a little doubt. But as I said in my comment, if the statement holds in  $\sigma-$finite space, then it should be true in any space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no counterexample, since this statement is true in general. I am going to extend [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/242792/1198970) answer, so that the argument holds for the non-$\sigma$-finite case too. I am using the same notation as used there.

When proving that $\liminf_{p \to \infty} \|f\|_p \leq \|f\|_\infty$ the same proof goes through, even if your space is not $\sigma$-finite, so there is nothing to do.
When proving that $\liminf_{p \to \infty} \|f\|_p \geq \|f\|_\infty$, the only thing that needs discussion is that $\mu(S_\delta)$ is finite. Now, by Tchebychev’s inequality,
$$\mu(S_\delta) \leq \frac{\|f\|_q^q}{(\|f\|_\infty-\delta)^q}$$
where the right hand side is definitely finite, thus so is the left hand side.

Comment: @Hermi your $f$ does not lie in any $L^q$ with $q\in [1,\infty)$, so it doesn’t satisfy the hypothesis of the theorem, i.e not a counterexample.

Comment: If you drop that assumption, then your counterexample works.

Comment: But note that if you drop that $f \in L^q$ for some $q$, then the statement doesn't hold even for $\sigma$-finite measures, as shown by the counterexample you gave.