A Multiplication operator in a Hilbert space: $M_h$ is bounded and $||M_h|| \leq || h||_{\infty}$
I'm trying to understand the example below, taken from Axler's Measure Integration and Real Analysis book.
How does one prove that $M_h$ is bounded and that $||M_h|| \leq || h||_{\infty}$?
I was thinking of using Holder's Inequality, $$||fh||_{1} \leq ||f||_1 || h||_{\infty}$$
However, since we're in a Hilbert space, $L^2$ has the norm given by the inner product, which is equivalent to the $||\cdot||_2$  and not $||\cdot||_1$. Also, to use something like $L^2 \subset L^1$, we need  to have $\mu (X) < \infty$, which we don't in the example. Therefore, I think I'm supposed to use another inequality, but I don't see which one.


@Mittens, I don't think so, since from the example I already know that $h \in L^{\infty}$.

@Mittens the condition for closure as a duplication is "question been asked AND already has an answer". I see that the answer to the question in the link proves that $M_h$ is bounded even though the question is very different. Furthermore, it doesn't seem to prove the inequality I'm looking for.

This problem has been discussed before in MSE. do some search. Here is an other instance. Notice that if $h\in L_\infty(\mu)$ and $f\in L_p(\mu)$, then $\int|hf|^p,d\mu\leq|h|\infty\int|f|^p,d\mu=|h|\infty|f|^p_p$.

@Mittens thanks for the link. However, risking your wrath, the OP there clearly states that he has already proved the inequality I want, and he's looking for the inequality in the reverse sense. So, all of the work is for the reverse inequality.

Also, I'm studying this by myself, so things that may seem simple/basic to you, may be very strange/odd to me. I hope you can understand. Thanks.

I get it now from your inequalities in the last comment. Thanks ;)

This inequality
$$\int_X|fh|^2\,d\mu\leq \|h\|_\infty^2\int_X|f|^2d\mu$$
shows that $M_h$ is bounded and that $\|M_h\|\leq \|h\|_\infty$.

Which inequality are you using, Cauchy-Schwartz?

If so, how come you have $||h||_{\infty}$ instead of $||h||$?

@Anoldmaninthesea.: Note that the inequality comes from the assumption, that $h \in L^\infty$. So $|fh|^2 = |f|^2 |h|^2 \leq |h|^2_\infty |f|^2$.

@ElDorado but what allows one to do $||h||<||h||{\infty}$, where $||\cdot||{\infty}$ is the essential supremum? Looking at this question answers, we need to assume that $h \in L^2$ or something similar to $\mu(X)\leq \infty$...

@ElDorado https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242779/limit-of-lp-norm?noredirect=1&lq=1
