# What is$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \left(\int_{a}^{b}e^{-nt^2}\text{d}t\right)^{1/n}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, limits

For $\left(a,b\right)) \in \left(\mathbb{R}^{*+}\right)^2$. Let $\left(I_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be the sequence of improper integrals defined by
$$
\left(\int_{a}^{b}e^{-nt^2}\text{d}t\right)^{1/n}
$$
I'm asked to calculate the limit of $I_n$ when $ \ n \rightarrow +\infty$.

I've shown that
$$
\int_{x}^{+\infty}e^{-t^2}\text{d}t \underset{(+\infty)}{\sim}\frac{e^{-x^2}}{2x}
$$
However, how can I use it ? I wrote that
$$
\int_{a}^{b}e^{-nt^2}\text{d}t=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_{\sqrt{n}a}^{\sqrt{n}b}e^{-t^2}\text{d}t
$$
Hence I wanted to split it in two integrals to use two times the equivalent but i cannot sum them so ... Any idea ?

Comment: You calculate the limit of the $L_n$-norm of $e^{-t^2}$, as $n\to+\infty$. Does that way of looking at it help you?

Comment: Yes I recognize it, but as a student, we saw $L_1$ and that's all !

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123222/convergence-of-lp-norms

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242779/limit-of-lp-norm?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main
page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730)
for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First answer.** This has some problems but now it is fixed.

So you have the result:
\begin{align}\tag{1}
\int^{\infty}_x e^{-t^2}\,dt = \frac{e^{-x^2}}{2x}+o\left(\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x}\right) \ \ \ \text{as} \ \ x\to\infty
\end{align} 
In your last step, you had a mistake. It would be:
\begin{align}
\int^b_a e^{-nt^2}\,dt &= \frac{1}{\sqrt[]{n}}\int^{\sqrt[]{n}b}_{\sqrt[]{n}a}e^{-t^2}\,dt\\
& = \frac{1}{\sqrt[]{n}}\left(\int^{\infty}_{\sqrt[]{n}a}e^{-t^2}\,dt - \int^\infty_{\sqrt[]{n}b}e^{-t^2}\,dt \right)\\
\end{align}
Assume $0<a<b$ $(\star)$. First note that $$\frac{e^{-nb^2}}{n}=o\left(\frac{e^{-na^2}}{n}\right)$$ as $n\to\infty$ (we will avoid writing this from now on). So use $(1)$ to get:
\begin{align}\tag{2}
\int^b_a e^{-nt^2}\,dt  = \frac{e^{-na^2}}{2na}+o\left(\frac{e^{-na^2}}{n}\right)
\end{align}
For $n$ large enough we can take $n$-th root on both sides of $(2)$ to get:
\begin{align}
\left(\int^b_a e^{-nt^2}\,dt\right)^{1/n}&=\left[\frac{e^{-na^2}}{2na}+o\left(\frac{e^{-na^2}}{n}\right)\right]^{1/n}\\
&=e^{-a^2}\frac{1}{n^{1/n}(2a)^{1/n}}\left[1+o\left(1\right)\right]^{1/n}\\
&\to e^{-a^2}
\end{align}
Where we have used $c_n^{1/n}\to 1$ for $c_n$ strictly positive and bounded away from $0$ and the fact that $\sqrt[n]{n}\to 1$.

$(\star)$: If you allow $a=0$, then something similar can be done which is even easier.

---

**Edit** One can also come up with the asymptotics of the integral:
\begin{align}
I_n^n=\int^b_a e^{-nt^2}\,dt
\end{align}
Assume $0<a<b$. Note that $t^2$ is monotonically increasing and using [The Laplace Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method), we get:
\begin{align}
I_n^n\sim \frac{e^{-na^2}}{2an}
\end{align}
Taking $n$-th root we obtain the result:
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty} I_n = e^{-a^2}
\end{align}

Comment: You summed equivalent, why can you ?

Comment: @Atmos I added something that justifies that step.

Comment: @Atmos Good question. I thought it is trivial to add them like that, but now I'm thinking about it, even the extra step I added might not be true. I make this answer better if I can justify that step.  I have added another approach and kept the first answer so that someone else helps me to correct it.

Comment: @Atmos I hope last edit. Now it is fine, right?

Comment: I love you ! Now it's full clear !

Comment: You are very very very kind, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

With $f(x)=e^{-x^{2}}$, by letting $M:=f(x_{0})=\max_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)>0$, we have 
\begin{align*}
\int_{a}^{b}f(x)^{n}dx\leq(b-a)M^{n},
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\left(\int_{a}^{b}f(x)^{n}dx\right)^{1/n}\leq(b-a)^{1/n}M,
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\int_{a}^{b}f(x)^{n}dx\right)^{1/n}\leq M.
\end{align*}
On the other hand, let $\epsilon>0$ be such that $\epsilon<M$, then there is some open interval $I$ of $x_{0}$ such that $f(x)>M-\epsilon$ for all $x\in I\cap[a,b]$, then 
\begin{align*}
\int_{a}^{b}f(x)^{n}dx\geq\int_{I\cap[a,b]}f(x)^{n}\geq\int_{I\cap[a,b]}(M-\epsilon)^{n}dx=|I\cap[a,b]|(M-\epsilon)^{n},
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\left(\int_{a}^{b}f(x)^{n}dx\right)^{1/n}\geq|I\cap[a,b]|^{1/n}(M-\epsilon),
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\int_{a}^{b}f(x)^{n}dx\right)^{1/n}\geq M-\epsilon,
\end{align*}
now taking $\epsilon\downarrow 0$, then 
\begin{align*}
\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\int_{a}^{b}f(x)^{n}dx\right)^{1/n}\geq M.
\end{align*}
In short,
\begin{align*}
M\leq\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\int_{a}^{b}f(x)^{n}dx\right)^{1/n}\leq\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\int_{a}^{b}f(x)^{n}dx\right)^{1/n}\leq M,
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\int_{a}^{b}f(x)^{n}dx\right)^{1/n}=M.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, this case it is easy since by continuity, for any $\varepsilon $ such that $0<\varepsilon< e^{-a^2}$ there exists $d>0$ such that for $t\in (a, a+d)\subset(a,b)$ we have

$$|e^{-t^2}-e^{-a^2}|\le\varepsilon \implies e^{-t^2}  \ge e^{-a^2}-\varepsilon>0$$ 
 therefore  for all $n$, we get

$$ (e^{-a^2}-\varepsilon)d^{1/n}\le \left(\int_a^{a+d}e^{-nt^2}dt\right)^{1/n}\le \left(\int_a^be^{-nt^2}dt\right)^{1/n}\le e^{-a^2}$$ you obtain the result by squeezing and letting $\varepsilon \to0$ afthermath. That is $$ e^{-a^2} =\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\int_a^b e^{-nt^2}dt\right)^{1/n}$$

> Generally, It is well known that for continuous function
>   $$ \max_{[a,b]}|f| =\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\int_a^b|f(t)|^ndt\right)^{1/n}$$

Comment: Not enough well known for me ! :/ I would like to use the equivalent I wrote if it's possible.

Comment: @Atmos now you know dont forget again. see the edit

Comment: @GuyFsone Hi Guy.  So, you have $e^{-t^2}\ge \frac12 e^{-a^2}$.  Then, $e^{-nt^2}\ge \frac{1}{2^n}\,e^{-na^2}$ and so $$\left(\int_a^{a+d}e^{-nt^2}\,dt\right)^{1/n}\ge \frac{d^{1/n}}{(2^n)^{1/n}}e^{-a^2}=\frac{d^{1/n}}{2}e^{-a^2}$$So, your final conclusion does not follow.

Comment: @MarkViola thanks so much I corrected the mess

Comment: @GuyFsone Guy, the first part doesn't refer to the $\epsilon>0$ you use later.  You're almost there now.

Comment: @MarkViola thanks once more

Comment: You're welcome.  And now ... (+1)